# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project dbproxy:

Tags: java, maven-plugin, hue

I'm getting the following errors when starting an app:

```
Error:

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.091 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-29T09:36:53Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project dbproxy: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 13.0.1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Makefile:53: recipe for target '/root/hue/desktop/libs/librdbms/java-lib/dbproxy-1.0.jar' failed
make[2]: *** [/root/hue/desktop/libs/librdbms/java-lib/dbproxy-1.0.jar] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/hue/desktop/libs/librdbms'
Makefile:106: recipe for target '.recursive-env-install/libs/librdbms' failed
make[1]: *** [.recursive-env-install/libs/librdbms] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/hue/desktop'``
Makefile:148: recipe for target 'desktop' failed
make: *** [desktop] Error 2
```

mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 13.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/local/java
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-52-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

openjdk 13.0.1 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you trying to compile to Java 13? What is the version of Java in your `pom.xml` that you are targeting?

Comment: Would we need to bump this line to 13? https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/maven/pom.xml#L41 Please feel free to send a pull request

Answer (score 2):

Your error says

> Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 13.0.1

You are using `maven-compiler-plugin` 3.0 however you need at least 3.8 to work with Java 13. This can be done with `<plugin>` tag, although you probably should consider updating Maven to 3.5:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>13</source>
        <target>13</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Take a look at [this article](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-13-guide/) to see what else is needed to work with Java 13.